# Get location of a user in Python Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I want to check the user's geolocation like the country code, and this is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://ipinfo.io/json'
response = urlopen(url)
data = json.load(response)
country = data['country']
print(country)
```

when I run it in my local machine, it shows my current location, but when I run this script in my ec2 server, it shows the region of the ec2 itself.

how can I get the actual user's location, not the ec2 region?

**Updated** and **Solution**

Thanks to Mousetail, i need to use IP in the URL:
`https://ipinfo.io/[the ip of the user]/json`

Comment: Use `https://ipinfo.io/[the ip of the user]/json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mousetail, I needed to use IP address in the URL: `https://ipinfo.io/[the ip of the user]/json`

Answer (score -1):

It is showing your location because the request that is being carried out is executed server-side, not client-side. You could use maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript) to get the IP from the client-side in JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: There is no need to use javascript to get the IP of a user, a server always has access to the IP. It needs the IP to send the data back

Comment: @mousetail Yes I know, but it's still one way of doing it.

Comment: @SergeiKiselev but I want to handle it on the server-side.

Comment: True, but that is incredibly inefficient, requiring a while extra round trip. Also you should never trust information form the client.